# CSS table-cell in Opera with :before and :after do not behave as normal

Tags: css, responsive-design, border, mask

I want to achieve the following effect in CSS:

[image]

I use CSS `table-cell` with `:before` and `:after` *pseudo-elements* so that they auto-adjust their width in one row. In other words, I want the text container have the width of the text (with some padding) and the *pseudo-elements* fill the rest of the area. This means that I can't use 1px `background-image` positioned top, because each word has a different width.

**[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9SBXn/1/)**.

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="box">
        <h2 id="header">UPDATES</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    background:url("http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-g-640-480-9.jpg") center center no-repeat;
    padding-top:50px;
    height:400px;
    width:50%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#box {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:50%;
    display:table;
}
#header {
    color:#fff;
    font:14px Arial;
    font-weight:500;
    line-height:10px;
    height:10px;
    display:table-cell;
    padding:0 10px;
    width:auto;
    text-align:center;   
}
#box:after, #box:before {
    content:"";
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    border-bottom:0;
    height:10px;
    width:50%;
}
#box:after{
   border-left:0;
}
#box:before{
    border-right:0;
}
```

However, **it doesn't work in Opera** so, I need to find a different technique to achieve the same effect. I'd prefer to avoid using HTML tables and any js. Can you provide any suggestion?

Comment: what is wrong with working with something like this http://jsfiddle.net/SteveRobertson/9SBXn/7/ ? seems to have the same width.

Comment: @Four_lo Nothing is wrong with this. It just doesn't work in Opera, so I need a different implementation. CSS tables and pseudo-elements don't seem to work in Opera. Any suggestions?

Comment: what if you ditch the psuedo-elements, can you still use css tables like so http://jsfiddle.net/SteveRobertson/9SBXn/12/

Comment: YES! dude! make it an answer. It works in Opera now. For some reason it doesn't with pseudo elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several tests, I found out that **Opera needs a more detailed implementation when using CSS tables with pseudo-elements**. In other words, it's not enough to set the parent container as `display:table` and children as `display:table-cell`.

You need to set the whole *hierarchy*, meaning that:

The parent needs to be set as:
`display:table`

**The first children needs to be set as:**
`display:table-row`

And finally set the other children as:
`display:table-cell`

If you set your CSS ignoring `display:table-row` like I did, Opera sets the children elements (after `display:table-cell`) as `table-row` and not as `table-cell`, thus the width of each child extends to 100% of the parent and behaves like a row. Setting the *table hierarchy* like in HTML tables (table > row > cell) you get the expected format.

This seems to affect only Opera, since all other browsers do not try to fix the *hierarchy* of the CSS table.

**[Here's the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9SBXn/21/)** *(check in Opera as well)*

Answer (score 2):

In this example I got rid of the psuedo-elements and sandwiched the header tag between two  that were styled as a table to get the line effect. Although this is done using a CSS table the similar concept should be applicable to an html table.

```
    <div id="before" ></div>
    <h2 id="header">UPDATES</h2>
    <div id="after"></div>
```

styled like so....

```
          #before {
              content:"";
              display:table-cell;
              border:1px solid #fff;
              border-bottom:0;
              border-right:0;
              height:10px;
              width:50%;
          }
          #after {
              content:"";
              display:table-cell;
              border:1px solid #fff;
              border-bottom:0;
              border-left:0;
              height:10px;
              width:50%;
          }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SteveRobertson/9SBXn/12/

Comment: Although I wanted to avoid any extra markup, this seems to be my only option. Thanks for your time. You saved my head from banging...

Comment: FYI I managed to make it work without extra markup. You may see my answer if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of CSS tables, you could use `inline-blocks` with percentage width and `max-width` so that the containers don't fall in a new line.